# Adding the ibapi library to PYTHONPATH module in Spyder (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.6, interactive-brokers

I am trying to simply connect to the ibapi (Interactive Brokers API), but I am having some technical troubles with Spyder.

**What I did so far:**

1. I installed the latest version for Windows from [here](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/#)
2. I provided the following path to the PYTHONPATH manager in Spyder: `C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\ibapi` afterwards I restarted Spyder

When I simply type `import ibapi` I get the same error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibapi'`

What I am doing wrong here and how can I fix this simple error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't use python very much but I'm pretty sure you have to install the ibapi.  I never used the PYTHONPATH and mine works fine in Spyder and Jupyter.  I'm using Anaconda.

I run the Anaconda prompt (just activates the conda environment) and navigate to the dir `C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient` and run `python setup.py install`

Then everything works.  I think many python packages need to be installed like this.

note: That's not my install dir, I just copied yours.  There may be a problem with a space in the path.  Try renaming to `C:\TWSAPI\...` if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Note: after `python setup.py install`, you might need to restart `spyder`. If doesn't help, then copy the newly-created `ibapi` folder to:

`C:\Users\iuzeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages`

or

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

copy your ibapi here
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/ibapi